# How Dapper.NET works internally with .Count() and SingleOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, dapper

I am new to Dapper though I am aware about ORMs and DAL and have implemented DAL with NHibernate earlier.

Example Query: -

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
public int GetCount()
{
    var result = Connection.Query<MyTablePoco>(sql).Count();
    return result;
}
```

Will Dapper convert this query (internally) to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` looking at `.Count()` at the end?

Similarly, will it convert to `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable` in case of `SingleOrDefault()`?

I came from NHibernate world where it generates query accordingly. I am not sure about Dapper though. As I am working with MS Access, I do not see a way to check the query generated.

Comment: Dapper is not a full ORM, it's a micro-orm, the functionality is very constrained in favor of performance, you can think on dapper as a data mapper, it will map the results of your query to a class. The right way to retrieve the count with dapper would be: *var count = Connection.ExecuteScalar<long>("select count((star)) from mytable");*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, dapper will not adjust your query. The immediate way to tell this is simply: does the method return `IEnumerable...` vs `IQueryable...`? If it is the first, then it can only use local in-memory mechanisms.

Specifically, *by default*, `Query` will actually return a fully populated `List<>`. LINQ's `Count()` method recognises that and just accesses the `.Count` property of the list. So all the data is fetched from the database.

If you want to ask the database for the count, *ask the database for the count*.

As for mechanisms to view what is actually sent to the database: we use mini-profiler for this. It works great.

Note: when you are querying exactly one row: `QueryFirstOrDefault` (and the other variants you would expect) exist and have optimizations internally (including hints to ADO.NET, although not all providers can act on those things) to do things as efficiently as possible, but it *does not* adjust your query. In some cases the provider itself (not dapper) can help, but ultimately: if you only want the first row, *ask the database for the first row* (`TOP` or similar).